# HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] is returning IPv6

Tags: ipv6, httpcontext, ipv4

Microsoft's HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] is returning IPv6 for the remote client. However, I need to use this data for a session logging table where the ClientIP column is varchar(15)... IOW, I need the IPv4 client IP address as IPv6 throws a string truncation error.

Is this doable?

Comment: You cannot find out a user's IPv4 address solely basing it on their IPv6 address. Total impossibility. (In rare circumstances (and only supported on non-Windows operating systems) the IPv6 address is included in the address like `::ffff:1.2.3.4` when the application uses a single dual-stack socket for binding both v4+v6, but that is a very unlikely scenario in your circumstance – especially given that, like I said, it's not supported on Windows.)

Answer (score 3):

No, the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses of a client are completely unrelated, so you cannot find someone's IPv4 address when they connect over IPv6. Maybe they don't even have an IPv4 address... Or at least not an IPv4 address that is unique. More and more ISPs will start to share IPv4 addresses between customers because they don't have enough IPv4 addresses to give every user his own. That also means that a user's IPv4 address can change over time, if the IPv4 address comes out of a pool of addresses that customers share.

You could try to make the user connect over IPv4 of course. But like I said: no guarantee that that will give you something useful. And in the (near) future it will become worse...

Answer (score 0):

The below code gets all the IP addresses on the server, as the server may have multiple network interface.

```
string ipList = "";
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()); 
List<IPAddress> ipAddressList = ipHostInfo.AddressList.ToList();
foreach (IPAddress ip in ipAddress)
{
    if (ips.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)//This will check if the IP is an ipv4.
       ipList += ips;
}
return ip.ToString();
```